# Argument of complex number under square root

Tags: complex-numbers

Background: This equation is actually from the book of Electromagnetism but here it's concepts are not at work.

I can't understand how to arrive at argument of the number \eta.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: Is it not one-half of the arctangent of the second quantity in box 10.33?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with $$\eta = \sqrt{\dfrac{j\omega\mu}{\sigma + j\omega\varepsilon}}$$
Square it:
$$\eta^2 = \dfrac{j\omega\mu}{\sigma + j\omega\varepsilon}$$
Divide top and bottom $j\omega\varepsilon$:
$$\eta^2 = \dfrac{\frac\mu\varepsilon}{1 - j\frac{\sigma}{\omega\varepsilon}}$$
For the sake of sanity, let $a = \frac \mu\varepsilon$ and $x = \frac{\sigma}{\omega\varepsilon}$
$$\eta^2 = \dfrac a{1 - jx}$$
Obtain a real denominator
$$\eta^2 = \dfrac {a(1+jx)}{(1 - jx)(1+jx)} = \dfrac a{1+x^2}(1+jx)$$
Now $|1+jx| = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ and $\theta_{1+jx} = \tan^{-1}\frac x 1 = \tan^{-1} x$
So $$\eta^2 = |\eta|^2e^{j2\theta_{\eta}} = \dfrac a{\sqrt{1+x^2}}e^{j\theta_{1+jx}}$$
And
$$|\eta| = \dfrac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^2}}$$
While
$$2\theta_\eta = \theta_{1+jx} = \tan^{-1} x$$
Or
$$\tan 2\theta_\eta = x$$
Substitute back in for $a$ and $x$, and you get the equations given.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Sinclair. I get where I went wrong